# Plotly code - viewer graph doesn't showup

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I am running the example code for the Slider function (example 2) in R:https://plot.ly/r/animations/

I want to simply reproduce the given example.

However, the graph doesn't show up in my viewer.

This is the codeI run in R:

```
 library(plotly)
library(gapminder)

p <- gapminder %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~gdpPercap, 
    y = ~lifeExp, 
    size = ~pop, 
    color = ~continent, 
    frame = ~year, 
    text = ~country, 
    hoverinfo = "text",
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'markers'
  ) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      type = "log"
    )
  )
```

I didn't change it from the way it is described here.

Can one help me and tell me why the graph doesn't show up?

Comment: just type `p` at the console/command prompt. You're assigning your plot to object `p` but then you have to explicitly call it to display a prompt, analogous to `print(p)`

Comment: Hi @infominer that helped - thanks for helping me R newbie :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run the code at start without success as well.
Basically the issue was :

```
Evaluation error: `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0 Please use `as_data_pronoun()` instead.
```

I think you just need to update your dplyr to the latest version 0.7.7.

```
install.packages("dplyr") #or update current version
```

Also check that :

- Any package larger than a few Kb gives the message:

> ```
>   Warning in install.packages :
> ```
>
> unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users[myname]\R\win-library\3.4\file2b884fc37c13\packagename’ to ‘C:\Users[myname]\R\win-library\3.4\packagename’

- If so,Type in : `trace(utils:::unpackPkgZip,edit = T)`

   and edited Line 140 `Sys.sleep(0.5)` to `Sys.sleep(2)`.

Then you can Run your code and print `p`
[Check out the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuQia.png)

btw a real cool one !